# How do I ceil number (etc: 5 to 10)

Tags: java, math

I have a problem with `Math.ceil` in Java, because it ceils and floors only decimal numbers. I need a function which can ceil or floor any number including an integer. For example if I have 5, I would want it to become 10 or if I have, for example 2, I would want it to become 0.

I am pretty sure that some easy function exists for this, but I could not find it. I would be really grateful for some examples on how to do that.

Comment: divide by ten, apply ceil, multiply by ten? idk xD

Comment: What have you try so far? Show us your code.

Comment: 5 to 10 and 2 to 0 is *rounding* factor 10, not *ceil*. `Math.round(x / 10.0) * 10`

Comment: Seems too easy, if this work I going to probably do something different then coding.... Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't Android related. Also, only use the Android Studio tag for questions specifically about Android Studio itself

Comment: Sorry for that, I edit my post. Seems like someone already do that. I just tried to get the answer, so I write as much tags which I though was related. You know when you spend a lot of time with something and it doesn't work, you just want as much people to see this question. I am sorry for that, I am going to be be better at tagging next time or more careful.

Comment: Stanojkovic: I am on my laptop, I don't have the there, I will update it in the morning, it's almost 2 am in here...and I was coding since the morning I am really tired. Everything works, but I got stuck on this and spent few hours trying to figured out.

Comment: It doesn't 'only ciel and floor decimal numbers'. It takes a floating point number and returns the integral ceiling or floor value, just as the Javadoc states. Nothing to do with decimals whatsoever. What you're asking for is unclear, or at best ill-defined.

Comment: Sorry, I was really confused yesterday.If you know anything about anxiety, you know you it could bring your IQ down quite significantly. It's tough, but yeah, I should ask question when I am not that dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class CustomCeiling {

    public static double getCeiling(double number){
        return Math.round(number/10)*10;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(getCeiling(2));
        System.out.println(getCeiling(4));
        System.out.println(getCeiling(5));
        System.out.println(getCeiling(10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, would this work wit long or do I have to cast the number. Ideally I want this be in integers. But I will try this, thanks.

Comment: You could've just called `getCeiling` without the classname since you are in the same class